# Replace double quotes to single quotes with awk

Tags: awk, double-quotes

```
BEGIN {
    q = "\""
    FS = OFS = q ", " q
}
{ 
    split($1, arr, ": " q)
    for(i in arr ) {
        if(arr[i] == "name") {
            gsub(q, "'", arr[i+1])
            # print arr[1] ": " q arr[2], $2, $3  
        }
    }
}
```

I have a json file, some data like this:

```
{"last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "name": "National Research Council. Committee on the Scientific and Technologic Base of Puerto Rico"s Economy.", "key": "/authors/OL2108538A", "revision": 1}
```

The name's value have a double quote, I only want to replace the double quote to single quote , not the all double quote, please  tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It's probably better to use a proper JSON parser in Python or Perl (or a standalone one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [need  help! sed or  awk  how  to replace  text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422103/need-help-sed-or-awk-how-to-replace-text)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/name/){ gsub("\042","\047",$(i+1)) }}1' file
```